# AJAX - possible to tag on request responses to the end of the previous response?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I mean when using the following to update an element:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Is it possible to 'add' the response to what is already in the element instead of the previous request response being deleted?

Comment: Just use `+=`? But notice that means the previous html will be reserialized and parsed again.

Comment: If i get the point why don't you use += instead of = ? Indeed :   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;

Answer (score 0):

Use `+=` instead of just `=`

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
```

The `+=` appends the new string to the end of the old string.

So:

```
value1 += value2;
```

Is the same as:

```
value1 = value1 + value2;
```